# Who or what? Questions about animate beings

Tags: word-choice, questions, animacy

Which of the words should I choose when I ask about the meaning of a word that I don't know exactly but I know that the word I am asking about is an animate being?

> What/who is a king?
>     What/who is a fairy?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When asking about the meaning of a word, the *concept of the word* is the object, not what the word represents. As such, you use "what". In your examples, you know that kings and fairies are animate beings, but you're not asking "who (among a group of people) is a king/fairy", you are asking "what (is the meaning of) a king/fairy".

Answer (score 6):

Who (or the objective form, "whom") is used when you are referring to a specific person or group of people (e.g. "Who is the Queen" if you are looking to find out about the person ruling a country [the answer to the above question is "Elizabeth"]). If you are looking to understand more about the definition of "Queen," then you would ask, "What is a queen?"